# how to disable the UI Interaction of a MAC App

Tags: swift, macos

we can disable and enable user interaction in ios app using

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

how to disable MAC App user interaction? we can disable interaction of a view but not the whole app. is there any solution?

Comment: I certainly hope not so.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is possible

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but at least judging from the answer menus will still be enabled so one can quit the application for instance and maybe also windows can be moved, minimized, closed etc, so not all user interaction is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable it using hitTest.

```
class CAInteractionView: NSView {

var isUSerIntactionEnable:Bool = true
override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    if(self.isUSerIntactionEnable) {
        return super.hitTest(point)
    }
    return nil
}
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
}
```

}

Call it like

```
  if let cView =  self.view as? CAInteractionView {
     cView.isUSerIntactionEnable = false
  }
```